# Convert DVD to MP4

Tags: windows, media-converter, optical-media, mp4

Does there exist a software which will convert the video content of a DVD to MP4 ?
It would be necessary that language and subtitles can be selected.

Comment: DVDFab does all this. Costs about $50, and up.

Comment: I think I used to use Videora for this about 10 years ago.
http://www.videora.com/

I can't remember enough for an answer, and I think it might be infested with spyware. Or maybe I am thinking of something else.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks! Costs are not so the issue, I've spent much more for the DVDs I want to convert ;) Important is for me the ability to select sound, subtitles and language. Think I will try the MKV approach (below) first.

Comment: @SQLPolice Could you specify the OS you need it for?

Comment: @mguassa Oh yes, Windows! (Win 7 and upwards)  Added the tag.

Comment: Should it be free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy, although time consuming, way is to do it in two steps.

[Make MKV](http://makemkv.com/) will rip the DVD to an MKV file, which contains the subtitles and language elements.

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) can then be used to create an MP4 from the MKV using the elements that you desire.

It is time consuming as each stage will take a while to execute.  However, it has worked every time I have used it.

Comment: that sounds promising, thanks, I will give that approach a try.

Comment: Hello @Chenmunka , late reply: These tools are both great! perfect pieces of software! Meanwhile I've converted all my DVDs to MKV format and I let them on the server in this format  (as they can be used by VLC player); and out of that, I've some of them converted to MP4 (for use on smartphone). Now my library is really great! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've always had good results with [DVD Decrypter](http://www.dvddecrypter.org.uk) and [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) or ffmpeg (which is command-line only and is what Handbrake uses).  I like this solution because I keep the decrypted DVD format for future transcoding and so I can watch it in it's original form with menus intact on a PC, and so I can transcode for different devices in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Format Factory](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/) to achieve this directly in one step.

It support a lot of video formats to directly convert them to MP4 format.

[image: Different formats supported by format factory]